# Override Available shipping method template from custom module not working

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, overrides, phtml, custom-template

I tried to override the core template file which located in

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml

like this:

> app/code/local/Test/ShippingCost/etc/config.xml

```
<frontend>
      <layout>
            <updates>
              <test_shippingcost>
                  <file>test_shippingcost.xml</file>
              </test_shippingcost> 
            </updates>
        </layout>
</frontend>
```

> app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/test_shippingcost.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <checkout_onepage_index>
    <reference name="checkout.onepage.shipping_method.available">
          <action method="setTemplate">
              <template>test/shippingcost/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml</template>
          </action>
    </reference>
  </checkout_onepage_index>
</layout>
```

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/test/shippingcost/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml

```
<h1> Success Override </h1>
```

the problem is, it still shows the old phtml file content instead of the new one

Comment: are you sure you are using base/default theme and not rwd or custom?

Comment: @Piyush yes because when i changed the app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml , it changed the content

Comment: as I can see in core files the block `checkout.onepage.shipping_method.available` is not added under `checkout_multishipping_overview` you may need to change your handle to `checkout_onepage_index` or if you have to add this block instead of  override

Comment: @Piyush still not working, see my updated question

Comment: your code seem right, try to move this files iin your current theme folder

Comment: Shouldn't you just add a folder under your template and add a file there?  Like:  app/design/frontend/ThemeName/ThemeDefault/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml

Answer (score 1):

In your module's XML file add dependency

For example

in your `app/etc/modules/Test_ShippingCost.xml` file would be look like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
    <Test_ShippingCost>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Checkout /><!--Add this depend module and that will your layout after checkout.xml-->
        </depends>  
     </Test_ShippingCost>
    </modules>
</config>
```